# Dimensional analysis with sums

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

Lets say I am given

> $$m \cdot \frac{dv}{dt} = mg - \beta v^2 $$

Where $m$ is mass, $g$ is gravity, $\beta$ is unknown units, $v$ is velocity.

Let

Length - $L$

Mass - $M$

Time - $T$

So using units we write as

$$M\cdot(\frac{L}{T^2}) = M\cdot \frac{L}{T^2} - [\beta] \cdot \frac{L^2}{T^2}$$

But then I get $[\beta] = 0$?

Comment: You want two terms in any sum to  have the same dimension. So $|\beta|$ wants to have units $M/L$.

Comment: You cannot replace mathematical expressions by their units (dimensions) .

Answer (score 3):

You can't add thing that don't have the same dimension so :
$$[mg]=[\beta v^2]=M \frac{L}{T^2}$$
and $$[\beta]=\frac{M}{L}$$

Answer (score 1):

You never subtract /add dimensions. Only dimensions should match for equations to be valid. So $[B]\frac {L^2}{T^2}=\frac {ML}{T^2}$. Thus $[B]=\frac {M}{L}$.